# should I test for undefined, null and empty string in my test

Tags: javascript, unit-testing, jasmine

I have the following piece of code in my `MaxNodeOccurs` function that checks whether argument is valid and throws exception if it is not:

```
if (!nodeTypeParamIsValid()) {
    throw new Error('nodeType should be specified and should not be empty string');
}

function nodeTypeParamIsValid() {
    return !(ng.isUndefined(nodeType) || nodeType === null || nodeType === "");
}
```

Now I'm writing test for this functionality and I'm wondering whether I should write a test for `nodeType` param being `undefined`, `null` or `empty string`?
Something like this:

```
it('should throw exception if nodeType is undefined', function () {
    expect(MaxNodeOccursService.bind(null, undefined, 0)).toThrow(new Error('nodeType should be specified and should not be empty string'));
});

it('should throw exception if nodeType is null', function () {
    expect(MaxNodeOccursService.bind(null, null, 0)).toThrow(new Error('nodeType should be specified and should not be empty string'));
});

it('should throw exception if nodeType is an empty string', function () {
    expect(MaxNodeOccursService.bind(null, "", 0)).toThrow(new Error('nodeType should be specified and should not be empty string'));
});
```

Or is it enough to write only test say for `undefined` to make sure the expection is thrown?

Comment: From the code coverage perspective, you need to test all of them :( Also, later on, if somebody changes this part of code, then unit test cases will fail.

Comment: @thefourtheye, thanks for you answer, I think I'll then stick to this approach. Just needed second opinion :)